# Android soft keyboard obscures input fields in mobile HTML5 web app

Tags: android, html, input, keyboard

I am writing a mobile HTML5 web application to run on both Apple and Android.  On the Android device I am testing on, I am having the following issue:

I have an input web control text box located in the lower 50% of the screen.  When the focus goes to the text box, the soft keyboard is displayed and obscures/covers up/hides the input web control for which the user is supposed to be typing into.  Only when the user types in at least one character does the input web control become visible and no longer hidden underneath the keyboard.

What I want is for the field being entered NOT to be obscured by the keyboard. When the soft keyboard is displayed, I want the input web control to remain visible.

This is on a Samsung tablet running Android version 3.2.

Please tell me how to accomplish this.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the the old Android browser. Unless this can be reproduced using some modern user agent this question should be deleted or closed.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way to solve this android (and now ios7 too) nasty is to use the inputs focus and blur events. if you don't have a footer tag change to a class.

In jQuery:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $('footer').hide();
});

$("input").blur(function(){
    $('footer').show();
});
```

Comment: Any explanation what your code should do? Why should the input become visible when you hide any component?